# Access Drupal views argument in the same views header or footer section.

Tags: drupal, view

In drupal views module, is there any way to access the arguments in the header or footer section?

What i need to do is show a more/[arguement-1] link in the footer section of the view. I've changed the input format to php and I'm stuck as to how to access the views variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if he's using the [Views Attach](http://drupal.org/project/views_attach) module, the arguments may not necessarily be available in the URL.

However, there is a method for doing this within the Views API. Below I need to access the first argument sent to the View so as to draw information out of the specified node:

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
$nid = $view->args[0];
$node = node_load($nid);
```

Comment: In his case the third line is probably not relevant but +1 for the method.

Answer (score 1):

If they are URL arguments can't you just use the [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/arg) function?